# Trying to write a Program to calculate the Circumference & area of a circle in C

Tags: c

So I tried to write a program to tell me the circumference and area of a circle when I input the radius but it don't want to work ( I am following instructions from a book (Beginning C by Ivor Horton's))
so here is the program ;

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    float radius= 0.0f;
    float circu= 0.0f;
    float area= 0.0f;
    float PI= 3.14159f;

    printf("Input the radius of the circle:");
    scanf("%f" , &radius);
    circu = 2.0f * PI * radius;
    area= PI*radius*radius;
    printf("\nThe circonferance is %f" , circu);
    printf("\nThe area is %f" , area);
}
```

Comment: Did you read documentation of [printf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) ? I suggest adding `\n` (newline) at *end* of the format control string, not at the beginning. Also read the documentation of your compiler (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Comment: OT: regarding: `void main()`   there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seem that works good

```c
 gcc t.c -Wall
t.c:3:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
    3 | void main()
      |      ^~~~
a@zalman:~/Dokumenty/temp$ ./a.out
Input the radius of the circle:2.0

The circonferance is 12.566360
The area is 12.566360
```

Comment: I dont why my screen is all black first nothing telling me to input but it stills take input so i write a number and it work but the input radius appear under with no number beside it

Answer (score -1):

The Programm seems to work pretty well. If you have Problems with

```
scanf()
```

Then try fflush(stdin);
Before executing scanf(). It clears stdin and stops a bug, where a scanf() doesnt clear a NEWLINE(\n) and the next scanf() just reads the NEWLINE so it doesnt have any normal input

Comment: I just tried it in my cmd the program work just fine i think my IDE was the problem

Comment: Don't use `fflush(stdin)` to clear `'\n'` from the input stream. If you need to clear a  newline from input, you read it (and check that you got what you expected)

Comment: @HAL9000 Hey, may I ask you why you shouldn't just flush it?

Comment: The standards for `fflush` doesn't define what is supposed to happen when flushing input streams. AFAIK, the documentations for the  Microsofts DOS & Windows versions just say that it clears the content of the input buffers, but it doesn't say that the input is guaranteed to be line buffered.

Comment: ty for the information :) you're right then